How can there be omitted variable bias in OLS? Shouldn't OLS always eliminate endogeneity?
How can there be Ommited Variable Bias (OVB) in OLS? Can't all regressions be computed without endogeneity?
For introduction, this is Greene (Econometric Analysis, 8th edition)'s entry on OVB:

Reformulating the question: Why doesn't $b$ capture all the effect of $X$ on $y$ and leave the error term uncorrelated?
For example - Suppose the correctly specified model ($R^2 = 1$) and $x_1$:
$ y = \beta.x_1 + \gamma.x_2$
$x_2= \delta.x_1 + w$
We see, thus, that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are correlated.
Now let's regress $y$ on $x_1$ with OLS:
$E[y\,|x_1] = a + b.x_1+ \epsilon$
Since $x_2$ is supposedly on $\epsilon$, $b$ should have OVB, right? Here is one objection.
Let's reformulate the equation of $y$:
$y = (\beta +\gamma.\delta).x_1 + \gamma.w$
The regressors can, thus, be reformulated as $x_1$ and the uncorrelated $w$. If that is the case, why would the regression have OVB?

After estimating $y = (\beta +\gamma.\delta).x_1 + \delta.w$, how do you disentangle $\beta$ and $\gamma.\delta$ in your estimated coefficient?

I don't want to disentangle it. I just want $E[y|x1]$ without bias.

Note that equation (4-9) in your snippet from Greene refers to $E[b|X,z]$, not $E[y|X]$.

Omitted-variable bias (OVB) is bias in the regression coefficient estimates, not necessarily in outcome predictions from the model. As Wikipedia puts it:

OVB is the bias that appears in the estimates of parameters in a regression analysis, when the assumed specification is incorrect in that it omits an independent variable that is a determinant of the dependent variable and correlated with one or more of the included independent variables. (Emphasis added.)

Your last formula shows specifically how the omitted-variable bias in that technical sense occurs. If you are trying to estimate $\beta$, the coefficient for $x_1$, then the coefficient $b$ has a bias of $\gamma.\delta$ in your notation relative to $\beta$.
You might still get reasonable point estimates of the outcome $y$ in your scenario. The magnitudes of errors in the estimates will, however, be greater than those in the properly specified model: they will be distributed as $\delta.w + \epsilon$ rather than as simply $\epsilon$.
Also, be warned that this can become an even bigger problem in generalized linear models that have a nonlinear link between the linear predictor and the outcome. Then bias in regression coefficients in some such models can occur without correlation between the included and omitted predictors; see this page for a worked-through example.
